# Unable to build this Complex JSON Structure

Tags: java, json

I have a inter-related Maps representing the below data .

```
{

        "Soft Drinks": {
            "Tin": [
                {
                    "Lean Apple": [
                        {
                            "name": "1 Litre"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "2 Litre"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Clear": [
                        {
                            "name": "7 Litre"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "10 Litre"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Bottled": [

            ]
        }
    }
```

This is my code representing above json data in form of Java code

package test;

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Post {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException
    {
        LinkedList<String> forTinItemsList = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> forBottleItemsList = new LinkedList<String>();

        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(); 

        Map<String,LinkedList<String>> categoryitemsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedList<String>>();

        forTinItemsList.add("Lean Apple");
        forTinItemsList.add("Clear");


        forBottleItemsList.add("Lemon");
        forBottleItemsList.add("Clear");



        categoryitemsMap.put("Tin", forTinItemsList);
        categoryitemsMap.put("Bottled", forBottleItemsList);

        // completion of Categories.


        Map<String,LinkedList<String>> subcategory = new LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedList<String>>();

        LinkedList<String> forLemonItems = new LinkedList<String>();
        forLemonItems.add("1 Litre");
        forLemonItems.add("2 Litre");

        subcategory.put("Lemon", forLemonItems);



        LinkedList<String> forClearItems = new LinkedList<String>();
        forClearItems.add("7 Litre");
        forClearItems.add("10 Litre");

        subcategory.put("Clear", forClearItems);


        for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<String>> entry : categoryitemsMap.entrySet())
        {
            String key = entry.getKey();

            LinkedList<String> list = entry.getValue();

            for(String value : list)
            {
                System.out.println(key+"\t"+value);
            }

            //jsonobj.put(entry, arg1);

        }


    }

}
```

Could anybody please tell me how can i build the above JSON Structure ??

I was trying with different things m, but i was unsuccessful , the problem i was facing is that i am getting the Bottled Array is also filling up with the same Tin Array items .

Comment: your snippet shows bottled being empty

Comment: for reducing the code , i purposefuly kept Bottled data as empty .

Comment: it doesn't match your java code, the strcuture you seem to be trying to achieve in java is different to that in json

Comment: Could you please point out to me where the Data is mismatched ??

Comment: The structure seems off. It seems that the value of `Tin` should be an object with `Lean Apple` and `Clear` as keys. Why are you adding and extra array in between?

Comment: Ya Tin is a Object of Lean Apple and Clear , where is the extra array i am adding ?? could you please point it  out ??

Answer (score 1):

To give you an idea of the unholy abomination things would become if you did it this way: here's the data structure that you would have to create to capture the JSON you propose.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>>> items;
```

So, feel free to implement this, but if it was me, I would build a data model and then map it with Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

there are libraries that do this for you [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Comment: I am using org.json for this .

Comment: GSON and jackson have a more developed api, its easier using them than plain ol json

Comment: I can chnage the library , but is it possible to get a working example of this . I was strugling from past 3 hours on this .